# Bootstrap simple css dropdown text not resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My text is not auto resizing inside the dropdown button (Bootstrap).

For the first two buttons working great.
For the third dropdown, not working.

See screenshot.
Output example :

http://postimg.org/image/6ege4r4o7/

HTML :

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">MOUSES & KEYBOARDS</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">MOUSES & KEYBOARDS</button>

<div class="btn-group" role="group">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="">MOUSES & KEYBOARDSsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss<br>test<br><span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
</ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works just fine ... the img you post isn't bootstrap look like   http://www.bootply.com/yxhAedX7y6

Comment: It must be an additional style that's doing this because it works with just Bootstrap: http://jsfiddle.net/vnxjz0cd/

Comment: It was my Magento CSS f*cking up things. Thanks guys..